# for extracting/retrived the report do we need to add folder name in package.xml

Tags: reporting, deployment, package

In Package.xml is folder name is required to fetched the reports. I need to fetch the 500 reports.

```
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>Report</name>
</types>
```

Comment: This is your second question in the last few hours on this topic, sounds like you are having a very bad time! You can use `ant listMetadata` to get the reports or have you considered a GUI driven approach like my company's app Gearset? (https://gearset.com)

Comment: I just want to know ,how can we do using package.xml.Please suggest